# SystemError: error return without exception set when connecting to the database using ibm_db

Tags: python, python-2.7, db2, robotframework

I am unable to connect to the database. I was trying to run an automation script through Robot Framework for which I installed ibm_db module using pip. But the error is so generic that I couldn't get it resolved.

```
>>> import ibm_db
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=<database>;HOSTNAME=<host.co
m>;PORT=<port>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<userid>;PWD=<password>;", "", "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

IBM Db2 database is installed on a remote server which runs on Windows 7. I am able to connect to the database manually. IBM_DB module version is 2.0.7. Python version is 2.7.9 and runs on a Windows 10 system. I was able to run the same script from another system with similar configurations.

Comment: Edit your question because there is Not enough detail.  Is your Db2 database local or remote? If it is remote, what operating-system runs the Db2-server product?  Are you able to connect to the database without using Python?  Which versions of ibm_db module is installed, which Db2-client are you using, which operating-system runs Python etc.  Give more details by editing your question .

Comment: I have edited the questions with the required details.

Comment: If you have a working-system and a failing-system, you must compare the two to find which component is misbehaving.

Comment: In particular, compare the versions (and bitness) of the components:  python, ibm_db, DB2-client  and when they are different, then reinstall until they are the same version and bitness between working and failing systems.

Comment: I did that. All the versions are exactly the same in both the systems and the error is also not very specific. Hence, unable to get the root cause.

Comment: Dig deeper. Check if the request from the failing workstation reaches the Db2-server (by temporarily setting DIAGLEVEL 4 on the Db2 server, and trying the connect from python again, then checking db2diag to see if there was connection attempt from the IP-address of the requester).  If there was no evidence of connection then the problem is on the client side. If you have a full Db2 client on Win-X then set its DIAGLEVEL to 4 and check db2diag after the connection fails. Check if CLI TRACE on client gives additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while connecting to IBM DB.There was DB2 Server edition installed in my machine, have simply uninstalled it.Now it is working fine for me,seems was having some compatibility issue with DB2 server edition files.